# python + matplotlib: How to make XTick Markers symmetric over the axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

on a normal matplotlib's plot, how can I format the tick markers of the x axis to "cut" the axis symmetrically?

Standard, it is like this:

[image: x tick markers standard way]

I want them like this:

[image]

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [ticks parameters](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params).

```
 matplotlib.axes.tick_params(direction='inout')
```